# Pass SecurityToken string to CreateChannelWithIssuedToken

Tags: .net, wcf, wif

I have a security token string which is result of `SecurityTokenServiceClient.RequestSecurityToken` call. Now I want to pass this security token to `client.ChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(...)`. What is the easiest way to convert security token string to SecurityToken derived class. I expected something like `StringSecurityToken` but don't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .Net 4.5, then the class you are looking for is `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandler` or one of it's derived classes. It has a `ReadToken(string)` method that returns a `SecurityToken`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokenhandler.aspx

If you know the type of token you will be getting then you can use the appropriate derived class directly (e.g. Saml2SecurityTokenHandler for SAML tokens).

If you might get tokens of different types, then you can use `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection` class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokenhandlercollection.aspx

This let's you configure multiple token handlers (including custom ones) and then have the framework select the correct handler for you depending on the token type.

In .Net 4, the situation is more complicated because the ReadToken(string) method does not exist. You can only process XML tokens. OK if your token is SAML, but not so easy if is is SWT or JWT. In that case, you have to define a custom XML based `SecurityToken` type that has the raw token embedded in it. Then you have to write a custom `SecurityTokenHandler`.

There is a sample of this for .Net 4 and SWT here

http://zamd.net/2010/07/31/using-wif-for-securing-rest-service/

You could probably create a JWT one in a similar way, maybe looking at the .Net 4.5 code as a guide.

Comment: Something that I had to spend time on and I hope to save others that: Saml2SecurityTokenHandler only defines override of ReadToken(XmlReader reader). You can only use that or you'll get NotImplementedException

Answer (score 1):

CreateChannelWithIssuedToken requires a GenericXmlSecurityToken.

You can easily new up one yourself passing in your string security token (probably as an XmlReader - forgot the details).